# Blazor Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider'

Tags: swagger, blazor, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a problem with adding endpoint to controller with Route. Can someone help me?
Here is the code of **Program.cs** I am getting this error :

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type middleware)
at lambda_method1(Closure , Object , HttpContext , IServiceProvider )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.b__2(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

//Link interfaces with classes
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is the code of Controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]// for specifing the route where this controller is accessible
[ApiController] 
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployees()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await _employeeRepository.GetEmployees());
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Error retrieving data from the database");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `AddSwaggerGen()`

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```